# Scheduled backup of in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory

I have a Domain Controller (Server 2008R2) and a client (Win7) in a domain. I need to do a regular backup of the `Desktop` folder on both machines. I don`t even know how to start that. Any help? Greatly appreciated!

Comment: You do realize backing up a desktop folder is not the same as backing up Active Directory, right?

Comment: Yes, thank you I am aware of that...that would be a simple archiving process I already ha a php script to back up  a specific folder on the server, now it would be nice to run that scrip on the client as well. Im really a beginner..started to dive into this few months ago...so every hint is useful